# How do I set up SQL Server LocalDB to run on a client's machine?

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

I'm using Winforms and SQL Server LocalDB to develop an application that will be installed to an end user's desktop.

- What do I need to do to install LocalDB to a client's machine?
- Which version of .NET do I need to have on the client's machine?
- What does the connection string look like in this scenario?

I tried the following connection string:

```
string config = "Server=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFileName=C:\\Folder\\dbName.mdf;";
```

I get the following error:

> an error ocorred.. cannot connect to SQL SERVER...Provider:Named Pipes Provider, error 40 ...."

Comment: @MurDeR  The link you gave me is not related to LocalDB, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add two backslashes before v11.0 or add @ at the beginning on your statement. So, your connection string will be:

```
string config = "Server=(localdb)\\v11.0; Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFileName=C:\\Folder\\dbName.mdf;";
```

or

```
string config = @"Server=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFileName=C:\\Folder\\dbName.mdf;";
```

Comment: Fantastic ! I just copy and paste the string from https://www.connectionstrings.com/ and I didn´t noticed that, Thanks

Comment: Which .Net framework it needs? Can I use 3.5 for this? Or do you know any workaround in .net framework version 3.5?